# Selenium IDE decremenation of stored value

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I would like to decrement value which is into the "store" command in SeleniumIDE

I mean:

```
store xpath count | anything... | variableName
```

This up it is the "basic" variable, where I store my value.

and nextly:

```
store | ${variableName} -1 | variableNameDec
```

I treid to: -1 and -- and it is not working :<. Do anyone could be so kind and let me know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that I found the solution of my problem in the other topic:

I used

```
execute script | return parseInt(${variableName}) -1 | variableNameDec
```

and after that- it's working correctly! :D

Have good day!